# Table design，select Scalable attributes

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis, entity-attribute-value

There is a commodity table

```
table field：{
   long id,
   long commodityId,
   long storeroomId,
   VARCHAR batch_property
}
```

batch_property value is a json.
for example： `{"a_property":"a","b_property":"b",...}`

Now need to restructure the table structure.

Can be selected according to batch_property, what to do?

Comment: Use EAV pattern.

Comment: More on EAV:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav